# How can i find data-id if tag A in table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple table :

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><a href="http:link" class="btn btn-default" data-action="view" 
 data-id="44">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like after click get a data-action and data-id i tried

```
$('#visit-list-table tr').on('click', function() {
    var test = $(this).closest("tr");
    console.log(test[0].data('id'));

    var test = $(this).closest("tr").find('a').attr('id');
    console.log(test);
});
```

But without result. How can I get this data?

Comment: What is `$(this)` in code?

Comment: aaaa sorry $('#visit-list-table tr').on('click', function() {

Comment: none of the elements in your HTML have attribute 'id'. You could try to get the attribute by its full name: ...`.attr('data-id')`

Comment: How about `$('#visit-list-table tr').on('click', function() { console.log($(this).find("a").data('id')); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below snippet.
You should use data attribute like

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('a').data('id')
```

Or

```
$(this).closest("tr").find('a').attr('data-id')
```

Both will give same result.
And i added id 'visit-list-table' to the table.

```js
$('#visit-list-table tr').on('click', function() {
 
  var test = $(this).closest("tr").find('a').data('id');
  console.log(test);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="visit-list-table">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><a href="http:link" class="btn btn-default" data-action="view" 
 data-id="44">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `$(this)` in event listener is `tr` but you trying to use `closest('tr')` that is additional

Answer (score 0):

add id `#visit-list-table` to element. and you can do `$(this).find('a').attr('data-id');` Here `attr('data-id')` instead of attr('id') because there is no attribute in a tag with `id`

```js
$('#visit-list-table tr').on('click', function() {
    var test = $(this).find('a').attr('data-id');
    console.log(test);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="visit-list-table">
    <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-default" data-action="view" 
 data-id="44">View</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```